# Mounting HFS+ drive over network, write not required

Tags: networking, partitioning, mount, samba, hfs+

I really need to figure out how to configure out how to get my linux box to mount a drive from my mac. They are permanently networked.

My Mac is called `fuzzy`, and has been set up to allow the `Movies` folder out via SMB. I ran `smbtree` and this drive shows up as `\\FUZZY\Movies`.

Things I have tried:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs \\FUZZY\Movies -o username=**,password=** /media/Movies
```

`Error: mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'`

```
sudo mount -t cifs \\FUZZY\Movies -o username=**,password=** /media/Movies
```

`Error: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on \FUZZYMovies,`

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force \\FUZZY\Movies /media/Movies
```

`mount: special device \FUZZYMovies does not exist`

Comment: What error messages are you getting? (Please edit your question to include this information.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I have included that information now.

Answer (score 1):

Use slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`).

`mount` will accept slashes, and the problem with backslashes, even if they are accepted, is that a backslash is also a shell [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). If you want the `mount` command to see `\\`, you would have to put `\\\\` on the command line.

So name the host-and-share you want to mount like this:

```
//FUZZY/Movies
```

With just that change, your mount commands (except the `-t hfsplus` one) should be correct. But I recommend writing your Samba mounting commands in a more ordinary fashion, like this:

```
sudo smbmount //FUZZY/Movies /media/Movies -o username=**,password=**
```

<sup>**Thanks [to Braiam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195757/mounting-hfs-drive-over-network-write-not-required/195759?noredirect=1#comment425183_195759) for correcting a serious error in this command.**</sup>

(Make sure `/media/Movies` exists and is empty.)

Even better, if you're invoking this manually anyway, leave off the  `,password=**` part; it will prompt you for the password and you can enter it, and then the password won't go into your command history (thus becoming visible in cleartext).

Comment: I'm getting `mount error(22): Invalid argument` now.

Comment: @MildFuzz Does it work if you use `sudo smbmount //FUZZY/Movies /media/Movies - user=**` instead? (And of course `**` is replaced by your actual username.)

Comment: Same error I am afraid

Comment: There shouldn't be using two `-o` switches. sudo smbmount //FUZZY/Movies /media/Movies -ouser=**,pass=** or sudo mount -t cifs //FUZZY/Movies /media/Movies -ouser=**,pass=**

Comment: @Braiam You're right; using `-o` twice doesn't work, or if it did (since I seem to remember testing it before I posted this), it doesn't work reliably or on 13.04. In any case, `-o` twice was probably always *wrong* syntax. So thanks for finding and helping me fix this!!